# PowerShell Function returning unexpected data

Tags: powershell

I have a simple function to look up some data in Oracle, and return an object consisting of the various data elements from the table.

```
function Get-OracleInfo {

[OutputType([PSObject])]
Param(  [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][string]$BindValue,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$OraclePath,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$OracledbConnectionString,)

Begin {
$Query="select stuff......" 
Add-Type -Path $OraclePath
}

PROCESS {

#get data 
try {
$connection=New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($OracledbConnectionString)
$connection.Open()
$OprIDLookupCmd=$connection.CreateCommand()
$OprIDLookupCmd.CommandText=$Query

#set bind value to parameter
$OprIDLookupBindParam = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
$AccountLookupBindParam.Value = $BindValue
$AccountLookupCmd.Parameters.Add($AccountLookupBindParam) 
$AccountRdr=$AccountLookupCmd.ExecuteReader()
if ($AccountRdr.Read()) {
$accountInfo = New-Object psobject -Property @{'StringVal1'=$AccountRdr.Item("field1")
'StringVal2'=$AccountRdr.Item("field2")
'Date1'=[datetime]$AccountRdr.Item("field3")}

}
}
catch
{
Write-Error ("Error in lookup Account - Can't open connection: {0}`n{1}" -f

$connection.ConnectionString, $_.Exception.ToString())
}
}

END {
if ($connection.State -eq 'Open') { $connection.close() }
return $accountInfo
}
```

it gets the data just fine in Oracle, and assigns the table fields to the object just fine.  when running this in debug, looking at the values for variable $accountInfo it returns an object with 3 properties, just as expected.

```
String1             Date2                     String2   
--------            ------------               -----   
StringVal2      5/11/2016 12:00:00 AM         StringVal2
```

But when calling the function from the commandline and assigning it to a variable.....upon returning from the function, it displays as an array with 2 elements.

```
$UserData=Get-OracleInfo -BindValue $account -OraclePath $OraclePath -OracledbConnectionString $OracledbConnectionString
```

$UserData[1] is the returned object (meaning it shows the object with the 3 properties of Stringval1,Stringval2,Date1).  The thing I cannot figure out is why it is returning as an array, and the first element (i.e. $UserData[0]) is an OracleObject.  Below are the details when running the command

```
$UserData | Get-Member 

TypeName: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

Name                      MemberType Definition                                                                        
----                      ---------- ----------                                                                        
Clone                     Method     System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                           
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)                   
Dispose                   Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()                                        
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                    
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                 
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()                                                
GetType                   Method     type GetType()                                                                    
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()                                         
ResetDbType               Method     void ResetDbType()                                                                
ResetOracleDbType         Method     void ResetOracleDbType()                                                          
ToString                  Method     string ToString()                                                                 
ArrayBindSize             Property   int[] ArrayBindSize {get;set;}                                                    
ArrayBindStatus           Property   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterStatus[] ArrayBindStatus {get;set;}
CollectionType            Property   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCollectionType CollectionType {get;set;}    
DbType                    Property   System.Data.DbType DbType {get;set;}                                              
Direction                 Property   System.Data.ParameterDirection Direction {get;set;}                               
IsNullable                Property   bool IsNullable {get;set;}                                                        
Offset                    Property   int Offset {get;set;}                                                             
OracleDbType              Property   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType OracleDbType {get;set;}              
OracleDbTypeEx            Property   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType OracleDbTypeEx {get;set;}            
ParameterName             Property   string ParameterName {get;set;}                                                   
Precision                 Property   byte Precision {get;set;}                                                         
Scale                     Property   byte Scale {get;set;}                                                             
Size                      Property   int Size {get;set;}                                                               
SourceColumn              Property   string SourceColumn {get;set;}                                                    
SourceColumnNullMapping   Property   bool SourceColumnNullMapping {get;set;}                                           
SourceVersion             Property   System.Data.DataRowVersion SourceVersion {get;set;}                               
Status                    Property   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterStatus Status {get;set;}           
UdtTypeName               Property   string UdtTypeName {get;set;}                                                     
Value                     Property   System.Object Value {get;set;}                                                    


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name         MemberType   Definition                                 
----         ----------   ----------                                 
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)             
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()                          
GetType      Method       type GetType()                             
ToString     Method       string ToString()                          
Date1         NoteProperty datetime Date1=5/11/2016 12:00:00 AM

StringVal2   NoteProperty string StringVal2=String2                      
StringVal1   NoteProperty string StringVal1=String1
```

Hopefully my explanation of the events and the problem make sense.....I'm completely flummoxed, so appreciate any assistance. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try throwing out the result of the add operation:

```
[void]$AccountLookupCmd.Parameters.Add($AccountLookupBindParam)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that did the trick!   I'd love to understand why this worked.....

Comment: It's because that output wasn't "captured", so it got added to the output stream of the function.

Comment: The behavior is explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return).